# In XQuery, how do you get a list of functions in an imported module?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I have a list of functions in a module that I want to call sequentially.  At this time, I have to also keep a list of function names, then use `fn:function-lookup` to see that it exists, then `xdmp:apply` and `xdmp:function` to call the function.

Is there any way to get the sequence of functions listed in an imported module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`xdmp:functions()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:functions) to return the list of all in-scope functions, and then filter to select the methods bound to the namespace for the imported module:

```
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";
xdmp:functions() ! fn:function-name(.)[fn:namespace-uri-from-QName(.) = 'http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin']
```

Comment: Turns out this worked well, then I found out that the function using this is called inside a spawn-function.

is there a way to add an "import module" to an xdmp:spawn-function?  Without it, the xdmp:functions can only find the built-in functions.

Comment: Worked out a solution - wrap the function inside the spawn-function in an xdmp:eval.  That allows us to reimport a library and redefine the scope for xdmp:functions.

Answer (score 0):

Never tried myself, but I think you could figure it out with [`xdmp:functions()`](https://docs.marklogic.com/xdmp:functions), and filter the full list by `xdmp:function-module()`. Mind thought, that it could very well be that order of functions is not maintained, in case that is important.

I also wonder why you are going through such lengths to do this. Sounds more like you are trying to run some tests or such.

HTH!

Comment: I'm using the functions as an ordered list of nodes in a record.  It could probably be done several other ways (like xslt), but this is where I am in this iteration of the code.

Comment: In that case, make sure xdmp:functions() returns them in correct order, or find a way to ensure this. The order in which they are returned is not defined, and could be unstable.